# validation in Datamapper orm

Tags: codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

hello below is my model

```
 <?php
 class Orm_demo_model extends DataMapper{

     var $table= 'orm_demo';
     var $has_many=array('post_model');

     var $validation =array(
         'name'=>array(
             'label'=>'Name',
             'rules'=>array('required','trim'),
         ),
         'description'=>array(
             'label'=>'Description',
             'rules'=>array('required','trim'),
         )
     );

 }

 //End Of Orm_demo .php model ..
```

And this is my controler

```
 <?php
 class OrmCtrl extends CI_Controller{

     function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
     }

    function index(){
        $data['title']='Add data';
        $this->template->load('templates/template','ormDemoForm',$data);       
    } 

    function save(){
        $obj = new Orm_demo_model();
        $obj->name=$this->input->post('name');
        $obj->description= $this->input->post('description');       
        if($obj->save()){
            echo '<script>alert("Record Added..");</script>';
            redirect('ormCtrl/','refresh');
        }
        else{
            echo $obj->error->name;
            echo $obj->error->description;           
          //  echo $obj->error->string;
        }
    }

 }

 //end of ormCtrl.php file
```

now problem is that it can't show error message when validation failed...

it returns following message.

```
  Unable to access an error message corresponding to your rule name: required.
```

Unable to access an error message corresponding to your rule name: required.

please tell me whats problem is there..?

Comment: try setting validation message for required